# How could an alien race convert an Oxygen-Nitrogen atmosphere into a Methane one?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, xenobiology, biochemistry, terraforming

For a story I'm working on, humanity meets an alien race of aggressive methane breathers, whose technology is as much biological as it is mechanical. When they locate a suitable planet for colonization they immediately begin terraforming it, transforming it into something more compatible for their species. The problem begins when they do this to a human-occupied world. So how exactly would you turn an O-N atmosphere into one comprised of CH4? Extra bonuses for biological methods, as opposed to technological ones.

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions. You have applied two conflicting tags. Choose 1.

Comment: You're telling me that you can't have a science fiction story that's based in science?

Comment: I am telling you to read the tag wiki.

Comment: Those tags are really just to define the degree of scientific rigor. hard-science is rigorously scientific, science based allows a bit of wriggle room provided its based mostly on science, science fiction allows a lot of deviation from science, but should still be broadly scientific, magic allows anything you want.

Comment: To second and third L.Dutch and Slarty. The [tag:science-based], [tag:science-fiction] and [tag:hard-science] tags tell us what kind of answer you want. That's why they're mutually exclusive. They're three of four unique tags. The fourth is [tag:internal-consistency] which has *specific rules* for its use. All other tags tell us what kind of question you're asking, but even some of those have expectations and limits. Gotta read those wikis. Which one will you keep?

Comment: Why would aliens try to colonise a world that's utterly hostile to them? "_Hey, this world has an atmosphere that's 20% highly corrosive metabolic poison that renders our own breathing gases explosive! Let's move in at once!_"

Comment: @jbh it's not mutual exclusive. It's a onionset, with the loser definitions containing the stricter ones. You can have science fiction that contains sections that are pure science

Comment: This is not a debate, @Pica. Those tags have been around a long time and they have specific meanings and purposes per their wikis. Maybe you need to go read them.

Comment: I'm not debating. I'm reasoning. Go ask a mathematician on set theory. Each addition of ever more fantastic elements, moves you into a set further out. The wiki is just a description of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Consider how your alien race uses methane for respiration

Humans breathe oxygen because as an oxydizer, oxygen reacts readily with most carbohydrates to form CO2 and water. We obtain carbohydrates from food, react it with oxygen from the air, and breathe out CO2 and water into the atmosphere.

How do your aliens extract the energy stored in methane (a carbohydrate)? do they also react it with an oxydizer? If so, where does it come from? This is, of course, an opportunity for you to write something cool with that, maybe they are born with a life supply of an oxydizing molecule and they die when it runs out.

If your aliens do oxydize methane for energy, what happens to the same waste products of CO2 and water? and critically, what is their tolerance to these waste products? humans do not tolerate CO2 buildup well, but maybe your aliens don't care, in which case:

#### Burn the atmosphere

Combustion is just fast oxydation. Burning enough carbohydrates (that i'm sure your alien race can produce in galactic quantities) could deplete the entire atmosphere of oxygen, as it reacts to form CO2 and water. the aliens could then collect CO2 (or leave it there, if they don't care at all about their atmosphere being 20% waste products) with their superior tech.

the nitrogen part is harder. there is however another way, if you decide the aliens care about there being nitrogen (humans, for example, do not.).

#### Freeze the atmosphere

Oxygen becomes liquid at -218C and nitrogen at -196C. While extremely cold, I would not put it past a race of galaxy-travelling aliens to have the capacity to freeze an entire planet to that point. Once the planet has been cooled enough, they could simply pump the liquids that have condensated and dump them in a nearby sun (probably even Sol, given the extremely low mass compared to the sun's).

Both of these options are, of course, a titanic effort, but i'm giving these aliens unlimited tech and budget.

Comment: I like the general approach, but "burning carboyhydrates" maybe gets you from 20% to 15% easily (and spectacularly)--beyond that point you don't have enough O2 to sustain reaction and need to constantly pump in external heat. Carbohydrates react with oxygen when they're hot enough, but plenty of other compounds will gleefully react at room temperature with no assistance. If the aliens are importing galactic quantities of particulate to powder the planet, it's easiest to start with fire but end in dust.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you need to get rid of the process which is releasing native Oxygen in the atmosphere. This means you need to wipe out any photosynthetic organism on the planet.

Once you have done this, the organisms relying on that oxygen for surviving will also die, and you will end up with a lot of biomass available on the planet.

Decomposition of that biomass will remove part of the Oxygen from the atmosphere and start create some methane, but as long as there is free Oxygen available, that methane won't accumulate. You need to add some oxidizable element in large amounts to capture that Oxygen into oxides.

Once all the nasty Oxygen has been removed, you can start inoculating your own native organism to create more methane and move the ecosystem to something suitable for your needs.

Comment: If getting rid of the excess oxygen is the issue, wouldn't burning it off be the simplest solution? Granted, we're basically talking about setting the entire planet on fire in that scenario. :)

Comment: Getting rid of the oxygen is easy. Getting rid of the nitrogen is much more difficult.

Comment: @Hewholooksskyward Burning terrestrial oxygen "gets rid of" exactly zero oxygen, it just binds it to (usually) carbon. In atmospheres below ~15% O2, most fires won't have enough oxygen to sustain themselves and will go out-- but that's still far too much free oxygen in the atmosphere to permit methane in significant quantities.

Answer (score 0):

**Not plausible**

Very basic chemistry here: Oxygen is an element.  Nitrogen is an element.  Carbon (the "C" in CH4) is an element.  Hydrogen (the "H" of which there are 4 in CH4) is an element.  Changing one element into another element requires not a chemical reaction, but a *nuclear* one.  Which means that actually converting an atmosphere such as Earth's into methane is prohibitively energy expensive since both hydrogen and carbon have lower atomic numbers than nitrogen and oxygen.  (I cannot be bothered working out the exact numbers, but have a look at how much energy is released in stellar fusion reactions to turn hydrogen and carbon into nitrogen and oxygen and that amount of energy needs to be *input* to fission the heavier elements back to what is desired.)

**Alternative:**  While the energy demands would be horrendous, it would actually be *easier* to strip Earth's atmosphere away completely, then manufacture methane in unprecedented bulk and release it to form a new atmosphere.  However, there would probably be considerable maintenance required as the methane may react with various exposed oxides in solid form (eg iron oxide), and best to take all the surface water away in order to eliminate all the dissolved oxygen there that could be released and react with the methane to form water and carbion dioxide.

Finally, while the quantity of carbon and water vapour in the atmosphere are disproportionately important for climate change, the absolute percentage of both is too low to provide the elements for a substantial methane atmosphere.

TL;DR this is completely impossible as a chemical or biochemical reaction, it requires either converting every atom in the atmosphere with nuclear reactions or complete replacement.

Comment: Nuclear transmutation is hardly necessary. Enormous quantities of carbon were removed from our atmosphere by entirely mundane biological and geological processes, and none of it required fusion. Free oxygen would take care of itself if someone turned off photosynthesis; it would bind into less reactive gases and solids. Nitrogen is trickier, but still solvable with speculative processes less extreme than alchemy.

Comment: @JayMcEh, for that matter, enormous quantities of *oxygen* were removed from the Earth's atmosphere during the early stages of the [Great Oxygenation Event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Oxidation_Event), pulled out by reactions with things like ferrous compounds.

Comment: @Mark This is a good point-- other posters focus on fire as a way of sequestering oxygen, but oxygen is quite eager to react with any number of exposed minerals and pull itself out of the atmosphere.